# How to open a CMake folder with Visual Studio 2019 without MSBuild scanning?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, ide, visual-studio-2019

We have refactored our Code Base from MSBuild (Solutions and Projects) to CMake. The central `CMakeLists.txt` is located in the Code Base root directory. Some of the sub-folders still contain `.sln` and `.vcxproj` files which will co-exist from now for some time.

I use a `CMakeSettings.json` in the Code Base root directory to configure CMake.

When I open the Code Base root directory with Visual Studio, the directory structure is scanned, CMake is called and anythings works as expected.

My problem is, that durrings the scan also the `.sln` and `.vcxproj` files are detected and processed. Is there a way to prevent this? When I use Visual Studio's "open folder" I want it to load only CMake stuff, no MSBuild.

Also, it would be nice if the Solution Explorer would pop up directly in CMake Targets View mode.